# jq join on common key

Tags: json, join, merge, jq

I'm very new to `jq` and this post is a result of not understanding the mechanics behind `jq`.
I could develop a bash script, which does what I want but jq and it's `JSON` super-powers have intrigued me and I'd like to learn it by applying to real world scenarios. Here's one...

BTW, I've tried to make use of the existing jq related SO solutions for merging/joining JSONs but have failed.

The closest I came to what I needed was to use an INDEX and a concatenation of $x + . , however I was only getting the LAST item from my second (c2) `json`.

So, my problem is as follows:

There are Two `JSON` files:

- `JSON` #1 will have unique "id" and "type" keys - among other key/value pairs, which I've removed for better clarity of my post.
- `JSON` #2 will contain multiples/non-unique "type" keys, which I'd like to match these two JSON files on. This `JSON` #2 will also contain other key/value pairs, which are expected to be contained in the resultant output.

My output requirements are:
I'd like to obtain a (one per line or a single array) list of all combinations of matching key/values pairs between c1 and c2 array where the value of the "type" key (string) matches between c1 and c2 exactly.

One more question, how much more difficult would it be to scale the solution to perform similar matching/joining between three `JSON` files at once - again on the same value of a particular key?

Any assistance or even just hints on how to solve and understand how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

1st input file: `JSON` #1, Array c1 (collection 1)

```
{ "c1":
[
{ "c1id":1, "type":"alpha" },
{ "c1id":2, "type":"beta" }
]
}
```

2nd input file: `JSON` #2, Array c2 (collection 2)

```
{
"c2":
[
{ "c2id":1,"type":"alpha","serial":"DDBB001"} ,
{ "c2id":2,"type":"beta","serial":"DDBB007"} ,
{ "c2id":3,"type":"alpha","serial":"DDTT005"} ,
{ "c2id":4,"type":"beta","serial":"DDAA002"} ,
{ "c2id":5,"type":"yotta","serial":"DDCC017"}
]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{"c1id":1,"type":"alpha","c2id":1,"serial":"DDBB001"}
{"c1id":1,"type":"alpha","c2id":3,"serial":"DDTT005"}
{"c1id":2,"type":"beta","c2id":2,"serial":"DDBB007"}
{"c1id":2,"type":"beta","c2id":4,"serial":"DDAA002"}
```

You will notice that type "yotta" from the c2 is not included in the output. This is expected. Only "types" which exist in c1 and match c2 are expected to be in the results. I guess this is implied by this being a matching/joining exercise - I added it just for clarity - I hope it worked.

Comment: Why wouldn't `{"c2id":5,"type":"yotta","serial":"DDCC017"}` be a match for `{ "c1id":3, "type":"yotta" }`? It seems they both have the same type?

Comment: You are correct. It was my omission, I will remove that line from c1. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of using INDEX and JOIN:

```
jq --compact-output --slurpfile c1 c1.json '
    INDEX(
        $c1[0].c1[];
        .type
    ) as $index |
    JOIN(
        $index;
        .c2[];
        .type;
        reverse|add
    )
' c2.json
```

The first argument to INDEX needs to produce a stream of items, which is why we apply `[]` to get the items from the array individually. The second argument selects our index key.

We use the four argument version of JOIN. The first argument is the index itself, the second is a stream of objects to be joined to the index, the third argument selects the lookup key from the streamed objects, and the fourth argument is an expression to assemble the join object. The input to that expression is a stream of two-item arrays, each looking something like this:

```
[{"c2id":1,"type":"alpha","serial":"DDBB001"},{"c1id":1,"type":"alpha"}]
```

Since we just want to combine all the keys and values from the objects we just use `add`, but we first `reverse` the array to nicely arrange the c1 fields before the c2 fields. The end result is as you hoped:

```
{"c1id":1,"type":"alpha","c2id":1,"serial":"DDBB001"}
{"c1id":2,"type":"beta","c2id":2,"serial":"DDBB007"}
{"c1id":1,"type":"alpha","c2id":3,"serial":"DDTT005"}
{"c1id":2,"type":"beta","c2id":4,"serial":"DDAA002"}
```

Comment: For everyone stumbling over this question, the used functions are builtins detailed under SQL-Style parameters in the documentation. This is one of the hottest answers on jq